# Why my AWS volume size is different from the actual size?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, disk

It's very wried to see my actual disk size is much less than the actual size. From the information, looks this disk is not be partitioned.

I have no idea why the actual size is 20G but disk size is 100G, and how could I find other 80G back?

The image version is stardard AWS Linux AMI:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2014.09"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2014.09"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2014.09"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2014.09:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.09
```

[image: lsblk shows 100G]
[image: df shows 20G]
[image: fdisk shows no parition and 100G]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try extending the file system to use all of the space on the block device:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/xvdb
```

The CloudInit software on Ubuntu and Amazon Linux AMIs has this command automatically run against the root disk when the system boots, so that you don't have to worry about making the root file system match the volume size on new instances.

However, if you create an EBS data volume bigger than the original snapshotted volume size, then you need to run this manually.

See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/414983/ec2-drive-not-ebs-volume-size/414989#414989